# Vue Provide/Inject - single object with multiple values vs multiple providers for each value

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

In Vue's docs about using provide/inject for the composition API ([see link](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#mutating-reactive-properties)), they recommend using a separate `provide` for passing along a function that can update the original value.

```js
const location = ref("North Pole");
const updateLocation = () => {
  location.value = "South Pole";
};
provide("location", readonly(location));
provide("updateLocation", updateLocation);
```

Is there a reason to take this approach over providing an object that combines the values like so:

```js
const location = ref("North Pole");
const updateLocation = () => {
  location.value = "South Pole";
};

provide("location", {
  location: readonly(location),
  updateLocation,
});
// or...?
provide("location", reactive({
  location: readonly(location),
  updateLocation,
}));
```

I haven't gotten a chance to dive in deep yet, but at a surface level it appears combining them would be nicer to work with since you're managing less keys, everything that is related is bundled together, and you can destructure the values nicely. Does the reactivity just not work?

Is what Vue recommends the best approach, or is there merit to combining objects into a single `provide` statement?

Comment: It's the single responsibility principal idiom. you're free to architect in any way that you want

Comment: I guess I hadn't even considered that because I'm so used to state being bundled together, thanks for point that out! Redux and Vuex don't really respect that pricipal, and now that I think about it more, most state management doesn't really follow it... Even React's `useState` method bundles the value and it's setter together. I'll have to spend some time thinking about how single responsibility should be used with state management, thanks for your comment!